# How to implement tag registration via Microsoft Azure on Android Studio

Tags: android, azure, push-notification, azure-mobile-services

I am following instructions at :
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-gcm-get-started/#sending-push-notifications

Instructions say:

```
// If you want to use tags...
// Refer to : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-routing-tag-expressions/
// regID = hub.register(token, "tag1,tag2").getRegistrationId();
```

Based on that I did the following:

1. added regID assignment to my code

My code looks like [RegistrationIntentService example via Microsoft](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/blob/25df6f43c09ab301587f9114de3948c1d548fdc9/Android/GetStarted/app/src/main/java/com/example/microsoft/getstarted/RegistrationIntentService.java)

except the line 48

```
regID = hub.register(token).getRegistrationId();
```

is something like this

```
regID = hub.register(token, "tag1").getRegistrationId();
```

2. didn't really implement anything in the reference link. Reference link assumes that I have an actual server. Right now I am just testing from Azure trouble shooting  test send center. (will set up server latter).

Right now from Azure trouble shooting test send center I can't send a message to 'tag1'. I know my payload is set up right but my tag is not getting registered in RegistrationIntentService.java as suggested in instructions.

Any suggestions?

Comment: it looks right to me. Double check your token. How are you getting your token?

Comment: String token = instanceID.getToken(NotificationSettings.SenderId,
                    GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE);                              //same as microsoft github example

Comment: Are you positive your payload is correct?  I fought with this for a long time, and got a non-documentation answer from Azure to put my payload in a specific way.  It works now.

Comment: i can send push messages just fine without a tag. When I add a tag then the message has 0 passes [i.e. no device to attempt to reach]. I know that I am not misspelling my tag name

Comment: I'm assuming then that you have this line in your payload?  `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("ServiceBusNotification-Tags", getString(R.string.debug_category2)+" || "+to_tag+" || tag3");`

Comment: ^ I think the line above is for "upstream" push messages, like individual user to hub. I am just trying to do hub to individual user, meaning "downstream". I will try to add that line to see if does anything .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tags are being added correctly.  I have a working version with notifications that send upstream messages to tags, and the tags are created in the exact manner you describe in your question.

The problem is Azure.  I have yet to find the correct way to send a payload with a tag on the test send server in Azure. The typical GCM format of

```
"to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a GCM Topic Message!",
}
```

does not work.  I believe this is because Azure test send server is doing something in between when it sends the request on to GCM.

When you setup your server, your tags should be working as expected.

Comment: just to be clear, you were never able to send "downstream" message from Azure test send server to a device?

Comment: Correct, not to a specific device.  I could send  downstream messages to all devices.